# Laravel 4.2 - storing in database is very slow for large amount of data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, optimization, large-data

I'm building an application that handles several thousand apartments per month. 
This means several inserts, updates and selects in different tables per apartment per month.

I've used in-built laravel/eloquent syntax, nothing in raw sql, as Im not familiar with it very well.

I have a button that generates the info for a month for all apartments. I wasnt very pleased of having to put all that in one action but it was required of me.

Now, every time I click the button and generate the info it gets harder and harder to process as the database fills each month. I assume its normal considering the situation. Could I get an advice on how to optimize this? I have to wait like 30 seconds - 1 minute for it to finish.... which is not ok...

This is how my controller basically runs (this is the main storing function, which calls several other functions):

```
// define month
$month = '01-04-2017';

// identify all payment categories (like water, electricity, maintenance etc)
// all these must be treated separately as they are calculated in very different ways
$payment_categories = PaymentCategories::get();
$payments_array = [];
foreach($payment_categories as $payment_category){
    $total = Transactions::where('month', $month)->where('payment_category_id', $payment_category->id)->sum('amount');
    $payments_array[$payment_category->id] = $total;
}

$apartments = Apartments::get();
foreach($apartaments as $apartment){

    $this->storeMainData($apartment);

    // each of these categories must be treates separately as they are calculated in very different ways
    foreach($payment_categories as $payment_category){
        $total_amount = $payments_array[$payment_category->id];
        if($payment_category->id == '1'){
            $this->storePaymentCategory1($apartment, $payment_category, $month, $total_amount);
        }

        // there are aprox. 10 categories of payments which dont have a common pattern so they must be treated separately
        // these functions below work similarly to storePaymentCategory1()
        if($payment_category->id == '2'){
            $this->storePaymentCategory2($apartment, $payment_category, $month, $total_amount);
        }
        if($payment_category->id == '3'){
            $this->storePaymentCategory3($apartment, $payment_category, $month, $total_amount);
        }
        if($payment_category->id == '4'){
            $this->storePaymentCategory4($apartment, $payment_category, $month, $total_amount);
        }
        // ...

        // NEXT I HAVE A FUNCTION FOR GENERATING THE PDF RECEIPT
        // NEXT I HAVE ANOTHER FUNCTION TO GENERATE THE INVOICE, IF THE APARTMENT REQUIRES ONE
    }
}
```

Next I have the storeMainData() function:

```
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), MainData::$rules, MainData::$messages);
if($validator->passes()){
    $check = MainData::where('month', $month)->where('apartament_id', $apartament->id)->first();
    if(count($check)>0){
        $store_main_data = $check;
    }
    else{
        $store_main_data = new MainData;
    }

    //main data stuff (like apartment receipt data etc...)

    $store_main_data->save();
}
else{
    return Redirect::back()
        ->withErrors($validator);
}
```

Next I have the storePaymentCategory1() function (which is an example of how other payment categories work as well):

```
// NOW WE MUST APPLY: total amount stored in the payment category / apartment percentage = due payment for the apartment;

// identify the percentage 
$percentage_type = $payment_category->percentage_id;
$percentage = Percentages::where('percentage_type_id', $percentage_type)->where('apartment_id', $apartment->id)->first();

// verify if the percentage type is applied to this apartment
$calculated_apartments = Percentages::where('percentage_type_id', $percentage_type)->get();
$calculated_apartments_array = [];
foreach($calculated_apartments as $calculated_apartment){
    array_push($calculated_apartments_array, $calculated_apartment->apartment_id);
}

if(in_array($apartment->id, $calculated_apartments_array)){
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), DuePayments::$rules, DuePayments::$messages);
    if($validator->passes()){
        $check = DuePayments::where('month', $month)->where('apartment_id', $apartment->id)->where('payment_category_id', $payment_category->id)->first();
        if(count($check)>0){
            $store_due_payment = $check;
        }
        else{
            $store_due_payment = new DuePayments;
        }

        // store due payment stuff

        $store_due_payment->save();
    }
    else{
        return Redirect::back()
            ->withErrors($validator);
    }
}
```

Comment: If this involves MySQL, please provide the SQL statements.

Comment: How many `$apartments` are you iterating through and how many `$payment_categories` are you iterating through?